# How to access object with a randomly chosen name stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, object

I've got 16 objects with names like: aBoard, bBoard, cBoard and so on,
eg.  `let aBoard = { currentValue: 0, valuesHistory: [], ID: "unitA", borderValues: [1, 0, 0, 1], free: true };`

I have an array of corresponding names, randomly chose one of them and change it so it matches the name of one of the objects.

`const BOARDARRAY = ["unitA", "unitB", "unitC", "unitD", "unitE", "unitF", "unitG", "unitH", "unitI", "unitJ", "unitK", "unitL", "unitM", "unitN", "unitO", "unitP"];`

```
let randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
currentBoardTile = BOARDARRAY[randomizer];
let temp = (currentBoardTile.charAt(currentBoardTile.length -1).toLowerCase());
JSObjectBoardUnit = (temp + "Board");
```

How to access the object using my JSObjectBoardUnit?
In other words, how to make JS "understand" that I want to treat JSObjectBoardUnit value (string) as a value of the object address?

Eg. Let's day JSObjectBoardUnit = aBoard;
Basically the outcome I want is: aBoard.key1 = JSObjectBoardUnit.key1.
I'd love to use the value stored in JSObjectBoardUnit to access the name of the predefined object aBoard.

Comment: I read your question multiple times and I still don't understand the expected behavior. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Basically the outcome I want is: aBoard.key1 = JSObjectBoardUnit.key1.

Comment: You can't dynamically access variables in JavaScript. You can dynamically access properties of objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand well your question but I think this 2 methode could maybe help you.

You can access attribute of a object with a string by using

```
const obj = {toto: 1};
const name = "toto";
console.log(obj["toto"]); // 1
console.log(obj[name]); // here we use variable and the result is 1
```

so you could store all yoyr object inside one and do this.

```
const allBoard = {
"aboard": null, // do not put null use your board
}

console.log(allBoard[(temp + "board")]); // display the temp + board attribute so if temps is equal to a then it will get the aboard
```

this is what you want, getting object from a string.

But I saw that the aboard also have an id attribute with "unitA"
Instead you could build an array of aboard, bboard ....

and use the `Array.find()` methode that will return the object that match the condition.

in your case

```
const myBoardArray = [{ currentValue: 0, valuesHistory: [], ID: "unitA", borderValues: [1, 0, 0, 1], free: true }, ....];
let randomizer = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
currentBoardTile = BOARDARRAY[randomizer];

myBoardArray.find((board) => board.ID === currentBoardTile);
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options

1. Put the boards in a list, and iterate over them with a for loop. In the for loop, use an if statement to see which Id matches the board you want.

```
let boards = [aBoard , bBoard, cBoard];
boards.forEach(board=> {
    if (board.ID == currentBoardTile) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

2. Create a dictionary where the key is the board id and the respective object is the value. Use the board id to get the respective value.

```
var boards = { 
    "unitA" : boardA, 
    "unitB" : boardB, 
    .... 
}; 
currentBoardTile = BOARDARRAY[randomizer]; 
console.log(currentBoardTile + " : " + boards[currentBoardTile]);
```